# Binding a variable to a input parameter in procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, data-binding

I have a procedure which gets 2 String as its parameter. I want to bind a variable to one of the parameter string but its not working properly as i do as below explanation. Your help would be highly appreciated.

```
DECLARE 
    customer_id Varchar2(100);

BEGIN 
     custmer_id := '100';
     Customer.Error ('CustomerEntity','Customer has already availalble for :custmer_id  ');
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `concatanation` operator (`||`) as follows as I think there is no way to bind the variable in assignment to another string.:

```
DECLARE 
    customer_id Varchar2(100);

BEGIN 
     custmer_id := '100';
     Customer.Error ('CustomerEntity','Customer has already availalble for ' || custmer_id);
END;
```

Bind variables are mostly used in dynamic query execution.

Cheers!!